# How to interact with a jQuery colorbox using the python framework Splinter?

Tags: jquery, python, django, testing, colorbox

I'm using Splinter with the Chrome driver to launch my site. I can interact with elements on the page. At some point I click on a link which opens (in Ajax) a colorbox. 
 How can I wait for the ajax response, then select/fill some fields in the colorbox with Splinter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use is_element_present methods to verify if an element is present: http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/matchers.html#checking-the-presence-of-elements

Answer (score 0):

something like this i guess

```
$(selector).colorbox({
    type:'iframe',
    ....

    onComplete:function(){

        //Ajax is done and now you can operate with this guy 

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm having trouble with Splinter. The Javascript is functional.